SwiftUI: How to reset child parameter when parent parameter changes in Custom Intents for WidgetKit
I have a configurable widget which allows the user to configure the busStop and busService to be displayed, for which busStop is the parent to busService. When a user selects a busStop, the users can then select the relevant busServices that belongs to that busStop.
My current implementation seems to result in the user seeing "outdated" busServices if the user changes the busStop (ie the parent parameter). In other words:
Assuming users have
1. Bus Stop 1
   a. BusService A
   b. BusService B
   c. BusService C
2. Bus Stop 2
   a. BusService D
   b. BusService E

When the user selects Bus Stop 1 and displays BusService A, then he/she decides to change to Bus Stop 2, BusService A is still being shown and can't be removed. Is there a way to clear the busService (ie the child parameter) on the widget?
Widget intent set up like so:


Is there ant code that you have done ?

@Shivbaba'sson well, I don't see any relevant code in the custom IntentHandling protocol that I could use. Some guidance here would be helpful.

Can u post bit larger pic, that show intent definition file, so i can reproduce.
